# session aware model methods in to_json cause n+1 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

This is an optimization question for an existing application, I've made the code generic to both make it annonmous and also easier to understand, instead of our proprietary models I'm describing a Forum discussion type situation. I've modified all this code for this example and not tested it, so if there are any typos I apologize, I'll try to fix them if they are pointed out to me.

Lets say I have a rails app with four models: Event, User, Forum, and Post.

the important relationships are as follows:

- User has many events.
- Forum has many posts.
- Post has many events.

The front end is a single page javascript app, so all database data needs to be returned in json format.

Context:

- when a User clicks on a post, an event is created with the name
  'Show' which marks the post as no longer new.
- The user needs to be
  logged in to see which posts are new clicking on a forum calls the
  following endpoint:
- There are multiple users so the events able is a many to many relationship between posts and users.

`example.com/forum/15/all_posts`

heres the relevant code:

Forum Controller:

```
#forums_controller.rb
def all_posts
    current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    forum = Forum.includes(:posts).where(id: params[:id]).take

    forum.posts.each do |post|
        post.current_user = current_user
    end

     render json: forum.to_json(
        include: [
            { posts: {
                methods: [:is_new]
            }}
        ]
     )
end
```

Posts model:

```
#post.rb (posts model)

has_many :events
attr_accessor :current_user

def is_new
    if current_user #user may not be logged in
        !!self.events.where(user_id: current_user.id, name: 'Show').take
    else
        false
    end
end
```

the model is where the action is at, so we've tried to keep logic out of the controller, but since the session is not available in the model we end up with this crazy work around of adding current_user as an attr_accessor so that methods can return the appropriate data for the user in question.... I don't like this but I've never come up with a better way to do it. We've repeated this pattern elsewhere and I would love to hear alternatives.

Here's my problem:

The call to is_new is used on the front end to determine what posts to hi-light but it's also triggering an n+1 scenario If there are 10 posts, this endpoint would net me a total 12 queries which is no good if my events table is huge. If I moved all the logic to the controller I could probably do this in 2 queries.

in short I have two questions:

1. **MOST IMPORTANT**: How can I fix this n+1 situation?
2. Is there a better way in general? I don't like needing an each loop before calling to_json I don't find this pattern to be elegant or easy to understand. at the same time I don't want to move all the code into the controller. What is the rails way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `Scopes`?, I think it will be worth trying.

Comment: Why not define a scope on Post which accepts a user_id param and returns only posts that user has not yet viewed.

Comment: @Jacob Vanus I want to show all posts, not just new ones. and then I want to use the frontend to mark the new ones as new. probably by giving the element a class of 'new' unless my understanding of scopes is deficient, theres no real way use them in this fashion.

Comment: I think that case is actually easier. Just define `Post#is_new_for_user?(user)` as ruby (not SQL). Then eager load event data in a scope `Post#for_user -> (user)`. Your controller only calls 1 method, your view can branch on `is_new_for_user?(current_user)` without making db queries.

Comment: @Jacob Vanus I think you might be on to something there, but I don't understand what you are describing. do you think you could post an answer? It sounds a lot like what I already have, the problem is that .where() will hit the database whether events have been eager loaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

If working with `scope` is an option, I will try something like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :is_new, -> { where(user_id: current_user.id, name: 'Show') } if current_user.id?
end
```

If is a better option to send the `current_user` in your case, you can also do it:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :is_new, ->(current_user) {...}
end
```

Comment: as far as I know there is no way to write a scope that will add a parameter like the methods block does. I want to return all the posts for forum ID 15, not just the new ones. I'll use a css class on the front end to mark the new ones as new. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was talking about [sending this type of parameter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments), take a look at the link and let me know if we are talking about the same thing. And about the post from forum ID 15, you want to return all post, but making a distinction with the post that are new for forum ID 15, and the ones that are old??

Comment: How about, adding a boolean field (`new`) to your model? with a defaul value of `true`, a value that later will be updated to `false` (with a business logic rule). In that way, you can return all your post from the forum, and in your view you can ask for that value to reder it in the proper way.

Comment: I think we were speaking of the same thing earlier, as for adding a boolean field to the model, that won't work because I have more than one user, this is a forum type of situation, so posts that are new for one user will not be new for another, hence the events table.

Answer (score 1):

This is just pseudo-code to give an example:

### First Answer

When I posted this I forgot you are rendering json from ForumsController.

#### Post

```
scope :for_user, -> (user = nil) do 
  includes(events: :users).where(users: {id: user.id}) if user
end

def is_new_for_user?(user = nil)
  return true if user.nil?
  self.events.empty?{ |e| e.name == 'Show' }
end
```

#### PostController

```
def index
  @posts = Post.for_user(current_user)
end
```

#### posts/index.html.erb

```
...
<% if post.is_new_for_user?(current_user) %>
  ...
<% end
...
```

### Second Answer

This is still pseudo-code. I didn't test anything.

#### Forum

```
scope :for_user, -> (user = nil) do
  if user
    includes(posts: [events: :users]).where(users: {id: user.id})
  else
    includes(:posts)
  end
end
```

#### ForumsController

```
def all_posts
    current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    forum = Forum.for_user(current_user).where(id: params[:id]).take

     render json: forum.to_json(
        include: [
            { posts: {
                methods: [:is_new_for_user?(current_user)]
            }}
        ]
     )
end
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, I might have some quesitons regarding making this work with to_json(), (I'm not using .erb files, the front end is a separate node project.)

Comment: Oops, I forgot about the json. Posted an edit to help with that.